# PolygonAlign Vendor Option

Tags: geoserver

I'm using this vendor option to get the labels to be aligned with the
polygon :

```
<VendorOption name="polygonAlign">mbr</VendorOption>
```

As stated in the description:

> If the label does not fit horizontally the
>
> minimum bounding rectangle will be computed and a label aligned to it
> will
>
> be tried out as well

I'd like my labels to always be aligned even if it fits horizontally.

Is there a way to force this ?

I've looked at the source code but can't find the place where the Vendor Options are enforced.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to force the behaviour.

I ended up creating a modified version of gt-render to achieve this.